# Marketing Cloud - Some Contacts not injecting into Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

We have a Journey/ interaction where people already in All Subscribers are injecting and those that are not don't.

We have a DE where our Salesforce Person Account data is being imported. We have created the Population to relate this DE with All Contacts.

We have a separate new DE which we use a Query to pull information from the SF Person Account DE and another DE that has am import of a Custom Object in SF. We are doing this as we need attributes from the the Custom Object to make decisions on in the Journey.

Having read other troubleshooting articles on contacts not going into journeys we thought that creating the Population would fix the problem but it has not.

My question is is there are a way to set up MC so that contacts from an SF import can not be in All Subscribers but still enter a Journey? If so, can someone advise what we need to change.

Otherwise, if all contacts need to be added to All Subscribers to enter a Journey what is the most efficient way of doing that? I have read a post about creating a DE, export to ftp and importing but the person who wrote it described it as hacky.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Contacts should not need to be in the All Subscribers list. If a Contact reaches a Send Email Activity in a running Interaction and they do not exist in All Subscribers, then they will automatically be added to the All Subscribers list based on the Subscriber Key relationship that you defined in your Sendable Data Extension.

Here are a few things that I would check:

1. Check that you only have one email address field in your Sendable Data Extension (used as your Population DE). Multiple email address fields can result in unexpected behavior.
2. Confirm that you have set the Channel Address Order in Contacts Configuration (within Contact Builder) correctly. Based on your specific contact model, you should have created an entry to include the email address field from your Population.
3. Check that the Contact met the entry criteria defined in the Event.

Comment: I have just reviewed the points: 1) we only have one email in the SF Person Account DE - it is called PersonEmail                                                                        2)In Channel Address Order we have added the email address from the new DE we create that is the pull of info from the SF Person Account DE and the SF Custom Object DE - this is first. 2nd is the PersonEmail from SF Person Account DE and then some other emails.                                                          3) The contact met the criteria as a copy of the data entered when added to All Subscribers.

Comment: Does the Channel Address Order setup sounds like ok?

Comment: In the New DE (where we are combining Person Account data and the Custom Object data) there appears to be 2 email address. One that we created to hold the info we are pulling with a Query called PersonEmail and another one created by the system called EmailAddress. We tried changing the name of our created field so this duplicate was not created and thought this might have fixed the issue but it has not.

Comment: You seem to have done everything correctly. This is going to be tricky to troubleshoot. If you [connect with me](https://www.linkedin.com/in/eliot) I'd be happy to setup a brief webinar so we can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Hi Eliot, thank you. I thing we have this issue under control now but it would be great to connect anyway. I am still trying to get a copy of the book :)

Comment: @KerryT, glad to hear that you have resovled this. [Connect with me](https://www.linkedin.com/in/eliot) and I'll send you a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce support were able to identify the problem.

We had set up the Population but in the Attribute Group we had created the relationship was with Contact Key (from All Subscribers) rather than with the identifier we had on the Population. We needed to change the relationship in the Attribute to use the Population. Once the relationship was updated and the person was added to the Population DE they would enter the Journey without already being on the All Subscriber table.

We did have a system issue when we changed the relationship. This could only be resolved by support. To avoid this, break the relationship in the Attribute Group first. Then recreate it. All the DEs that you have set up at Populations will be at the very bottom of the list when you try to create the relationship so you will have to scroll all the way down to find them.